# Collection field is null when instantiating instance of the class

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a created an object that will hold errors encountered as well as a boolean field to indicate if any errors were present at all. The class looks like this.

```
public class ValidationResult
{
    public bool IsValid{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

I go to use an instance of this class in a validation method as such

```
public class ValidationService
{
    // This instance will hold the errors if there are any
    ValidationResult myValidationResult = new ValidationResult();

    public void ValidationMethod()
    {
       // Validation takes place here
       ...
       // Some errors occurred to lets add then to the instance of the ValidationResult object
       myValidationResult.IsValid = false;
       myValidationResult.Errors.Add("An error occurred here are the details");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Errors collection in the instance `myValidationResult` is null? Why is this? I created an instance of the class and the boolean property `IsValid` is available, yet the `Errors` collection is `null`.

Comment: The List is not initialized.

    public class ValidationResult
    {
        public bool IsValid{ get; set; }
        public List<string> Errors { get; set; }

        public ValidationResult()
        {
            Errors = new List<string>();

    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize your Errors property:

```
public class ValidationResult
{
     public ValidationResult()
     {
          Errors = new List<string>();
     }

    public bool IsValid{ get { return (Errors.Count() == 0); } }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And figure out what you want your IsValid property to default to. If unset, it will default to false.

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel like an idiot. The Errors field is a reference type and therefore needs to be initialized. If I want the default of the `IsValid` property to be false is it considered good practice to leave it to the default  or should I explicitly set it to false?

Comment: It all depends on how you craft your class. For instance, one such approach would be to make the IsValid flag a calculated boolean, dependent on the count of errors. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: And don't feel bad. We all go thorough these things... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Only value types are initialized per default. Your `List<string>` is a reference type and it does have it default value - null.

Look here for a little bit more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691171(v=vs.71).aspx